# What is a noun clause?

Tags: pronouns, nouns, clauses, subject-complement, noun-clause

That was she woke up in the middle of the night.

Is the clause [she woke up in the middle of the night] a noun clause?

Thank you.

Comment: In standard English "She woke up..."  The past tense of wake is woke.

Comment: Is this a sentence you wrote, or are you quoting it from somewhere?

Comment: Thanks, I wrote the sentence.

Comment: "This is a sentence I wrote."  By the same token, is "a sentence I wrote" a noun clause?  Thanks a lot.

Comment: The problem is that it's ungrammatical.  "That was when she woke up in the middle of the night," perhaps.  What do you intend it to mean?

Comment: I just want to figure out the possible structures of noun clauses, i.e. begin with pronouns, begin with "she", begin with nouns etc.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: Your sentence is ungrammatical. How can a _that_ clause be complement of "be" in your example? However, I have dealt with the concept of 'noun clauses' in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

### About Noun Clauses

A noun clause contains a subject and a verb. It functions as a noun in a sentence. Or to put it another way, if the noun clause is replaced by a simple noun or a pronoun, the sentence still makes sense. A noun clause can function as the subject of a sentence,  as the direct object of the main verb of a sentence, as a subject complement, or in other roles within the sentence. A noun clause is normally a ***dependent clause***, that is, it does not constitute a valid sentence on its own.

A noun clause usually starts with a subordinating conjunction, one of: *that*, *if*, *whether*, the *wh-* words, and the *wh-eve* words. In some cases, however, the conjunction is omitted.

### Examples

Some examples of sentences with noun clauses (the words in **bold**) are:

> - **What Frank said** made his friends happy.
> - Do you know **where Joan went**?
> - He didn't know **why the program failed**.
> - Julia's  problem was **that she lacked experience**,
> - David is not responsible for *what Lambie says in a comment

### Function in a Sentence

Whether a clause is a noun clause or not depends on how it is used in a sentence. The same string of words can be a noun clause in one sentence, and an adjective clause in a different sentence. For example

> - My aunt is the woman **that works in the bakery**
>   [Noun clause in bold]
> - The woman **that works in the bakery** is my aunt.
>   [Adjective clause, aka relative clause, in bold]
> - They don't yet know **that you hit** the car.
>   [Noun clause in bold]
> - The car **that you hit** belongs to John.
>   [Adjective clause, aka relative clause, in bold]

This a string of worfsd cannot be identified with assurance as a noun clause in teh absence of a valid sentence  that uses it as a noun clause.

### Example From the Question

The problem with the example in the question is that

> That was she waked up in the middle of the night.

is not a valid sentence. And even if it were, a noun clause does nto normally start with a personal pronoun such as "she"/

### Sources

Some web pages about noun clauses and relateds matters:

- ["Noun Clause: What It Is and How to Identify It"](https://grammar.yourdictionary.com/parts-of-speech/nouns/noun-clause.html) from *YourDictionary*;
- ["What Are Noun Clauses? (with Examples)"](https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/noun_clauses.htm) from *Grammar Monster*;
- ["Noun Clause Grammar Guide: How to Identify Noun Clauses"](https://www.masterclass.com/articles/noun-clause-examples#how-noun-clauses-work) from *Master Class*;
- ["The Forms and Functions of Clauses in English Grammar"](https://parentingpatch.com/forms-functions-clauses-english-grammar/) from *Parenting Patch*.

Comment: Except that modern grammar rejects the existence of 'noun clauses'. You ought to mention that important point in your answer

Comment: @Bill, not something I was aware of, nor do  any of the reliable sources I found say so. Much of "modern grimmer" strikes me as of little use for learners.  Your source would be?

Comment: Thank you.  It helps.

Answer (score -1):

Preliminary point: modern grammar rejects the idea that clauses can somehow be nouns, i.e. noun clauses.

In the vast majority of cases, the clauses that traditional grammar calls 'noun clauses' are in fact content clauses functioning as complements or subjects:

[1] *I know* [*that she woke up in the middle of the night*].

[2] [*That she woke up in the middle of the night*]  *worried us*.

The bracketed expressions in those examples are not nouns or noun clauses. They are both declarative content clauses functioning in [1] as complement of "know" and in [2] as subject.

The fact that the clauses can be replaced by nouns is irrelevant. In many cases the so-called noun clauses can't. Consider these examples:

[3] *The suggestion* [*that they cheated*] *was quite outrageous.*

[4] *I'm afraid* [*I haven't had time to read the report*].

[5] *She objected* [*that there was no public transport available*].

[6] *It seems* [*that they simply made a mistake*].

The bracketed subordinate clauses in [3]-[6] are traditionally classified as noun clauses and yet they are not replaceable by nouns (or NPs) in these constructions.

Modern grammar argues that the classification of finite subordinate clauses is based on their internal form rather than spurious analogies with the parts of speech.

Comment: Thank you.  It helps.